# Showing $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \sin (xy) / xy = 1$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

How could we show that $$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{\sin xy}{xy}=1$$

??

Could you give me some hints ??

**EDIT:**

Could we show it as followed??

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\sin xy}{xy}$$ 
$$ x \rightarrow 0, y \rightarrow 0$$
$$\xi=xy \rightarrow 0$$ 
$$\frac{\sin xy}{xy}=\frac{\sin \xi }{\xi}\overset{ \xi \rightarrow 0 }{\rightarrow } 1$$

Is this correct?? Could I improve something??

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$?

Comment: Yes, I know... @Arthur

Comment: Could we use this to show that $$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{\sin xy}{xy}=1$$ ?? How?? @Arthur

Comment: Hint: Use a small neighborhood of $(0,0)$ to show that as $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$, $xy$ tends to zero.

Comment: Try to show that both $x^2+y^2$ and $x+y$ approach zero.

Comment: I have added my initial post... Could you take a look and tell me if we show it in that way??

Comment: There are more questions marks than dollar signs in this post. I've edited the title to make it meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the Taylor series for sin(z) then you can expand it for $z=x \cdot y$. Then divide by $x \cdot y$

Comment: Is using Taylor series the only way to show it?? @Zach466920

Comment: @MaryStar Certainly is the easiest, assuming you know the expansion. Otherwise you need to do the multivariate analog of the squeeze theorem.

Comment: are you saying that $\lim_{x,y) \to (0,0) xy = 0,$  and $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h}$ are not sufficient to conclude that the limit is $1?$

Comment: @abel Ed0's answer works as well.

Comment: I have added my initial post... Could you take a look and tell me if we show it in that way??

Answer (score 2):

Show first that  $\underset{x\to0}{\lim}\underset{y\to0}{\lim} \dfrac{\sin xy}{xy}$ is $1$, then show that  $\underset{y\to0}{\lim}\underset{x\to0}{\lim} \dfrac{\sin xy}{xy}$ is $1$, then show that if $x$ and $y$ are functions that depend on a parameter $t$ where $\underset{t\to t_{0}}{\lim} x(t) = \underset{t\to t_{0}}{\lim} y(t) = 0$ then  $\underset{t\to t_{0}}{\lim} \dfrac{\sin (x(t)y(t))}{x(t)y(t)} = 1$ for any kind of parametrization.

---

first you have to know that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\cos x}{1} = 1$$ (I used L'Hopital)

Let's do the first:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0} \dfrac{\sin xy}{xy} = \lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to0} \dfrac{x\cos{xy}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\cos{xy}}{1} = \lim_{x\to 0}1 = 1$$

Let's do the second :

$$\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{\sin xy}{xy} = \lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{y\cos{xy}}{y} = \lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos{xy}}{1} = \lim_{y\to 0}1 = 1$$

For the third part we do a little trick, we declare that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are differentiables on the neighborhood of $t_0$ and $x(t_0)=y(t_0)=0$ so:

$$\lim_{t\to t_0} \dfrac{\sin (x(t)y(t))}{x(t)y(t)}= \lim_{t\to t_0} \dfrac{\cos (x(t)y(t))(x'(t)y(t)+y'(t)x(t))}{x'(t)y(t)+y'(t)x(t)}=\lim_{t\to t_0}\cos (x(t)y(t)) =\cos(0\cdot0)=1$$

Comment: I have added my initial post... Could you take a look and tell me if we show it in that way??