# Limit of $\sin(xyz)/xyz$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the limit of $\dfrac{\sin(xyz)}{xyz}$ when all $x,y,z$ go to zero?

P.S. I think the answer is $1,$ since the limit of $\sin(m)/m$ is zero as $m$ goes to $0$.

Comment: This is just a hint: you can look [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208085/showing-lim-x-y-to-0-0-sin-xy-xy-1), in which, we only consider the case $\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}$ when x, y go to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple proof:   Let $w=xyz$, $w\to 0$, when $x$ or $y$ or $z\to 0$.  Then the upshot is simply $\frac{sin(w)}{w}\to 1$, since $w\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

It would be 1 because the limit of $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ as $x$ approaches 0 is 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined on the three axis planes $x=0$, $y=0$ and $z=0$ so has no limit near $(0,0,0)$

Comment: Sorry, would you mind clarifying what "it" precisely is undefined and how that implies the limit does not exist?

Comment: When $xyz=0$, $\sin(0)/0$ is undefined.  In one dimension that doesn't matter because the limit excludes the point $x=0$, but in three dimensions there are many points as close to zero as you like, where the function is undefined.

Comment: Please mention that elaboration in your answer!